# RxJs not updating the UI binded array variable

Tags: angular, rxjs

While using rxjs library for subscribing subject I'm getting the emitted data in console but the corresponding UI bind list to iterate and counter for length of data is not getting updated. I have written required console log statement which indicates that rxjs is emitting data and setting the required variable change is not getting reflected in UI.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/observablesrxjs

Comment: In which template and which service?

Comment: lessons-counter.component
lessons-list.component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the immortal "what is `this`" JavaScript problem. Changing the `next` methods to arrow functions helped: instead of

```
  next(data: Lesson[]) {
```

declare them

```
  next = (data: Lesson[]) => {
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/observablesrxjs-9ofh84?file=src/app/lessons-list/lessons-list.component.ts

(Don't ask me *why*, though, I personally haven't used this "component is observer" pattern).